# How to create list with Ids representing index of each record(like associative array )?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I have a json structure like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Tables> Tables { get; set; }
}

public class Tables
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Columns { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I am creating this structure:

```
var Ids =  new List<int>();
Ids.Add(100);
Ids.Add(101);
Ids.Add(102);

var list = new List<MyModel>();
foreach (var item in Ids)
{
    list.Add(
       new MyModel
       {
           Id = item,
           Tables = GetTables()
       }
    );
}


public List<Tables> GetTables()
{
    from table in connection.GetSchema("Tables").AsEnumerable()
    let name = (string)table["TABLE_NAME"]
    let catalog = (string)table["TABLE_CATALOG"]
    let schema = (string)table["TABLE_SCHEMA"]
    select new Tables 
       Name = name,
       Columns =
          from column in connection.GetSchema("Columns", new [] { catalog, schema, name }).AsEnumerable()
          select (string)column["COLUMN_NAME"]).ToArray()
}).ToList();
```

It is possible to have data like this :

```
[101] : List of tables
[102] : List of tables
[103] : List of tables
```

Right now i am doing this on client side(ie in **javascript**) like below:

```
var list = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
     list[response.Id] = { tables: response[i].tables };
}
```

So can i create same response like above on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create using Dictionary.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<int, List<Tables>> MyModel { get; set; }
}
```

You have to pass id as a key and list of tables as a value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash table.after getting your data for **list variable**.then looping the your list variable and add to hash table.

```
 Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
        foreach (MyModel myItem in yourlistvariable)
        {
            if (!hashtable.ContainsKey(myItem.Id))
            {
                hashtable[myItem.Id] = myItem.Tables;
            }
        }
```

finally in hashtable variable you have data how you want

Comment: since Generics and Dictionary are in .Net (long time, actually) using Hashtable is not the way to go.

Comment: yes.you can use dictionary for type safety rather than hash table.